# Mapping points on a clean US map (50 states)

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2

I  want to plot points on a clean US map (i.e., the US map only on white background with no topography or text). Here is sample data (my actual data has 50,000 points).

```
DATA <- data.frame(Lat=c(47.339374,39.693737, 29.757914, 19.543946,64.668754),
           Long=c(-118.0652,-82.765102,-97.929229,-155.581094,-148.926691),
           State= c("Washington","Ohio","Texas","Hawaii","Alaska") )
```

I tried this using maps, but Alaska and Hawaii are not showing up and I want them included in the map.

```
library(maps)
map("state", interior = FALSE)
map("state", boundary = FALSE, lty = 2, col=8, lwd=0.5, add = TRUE)
title("US map")
points(DATA$Long, DATA$Lat, pch=19, cex=0.5, col= 1:nrow(DATA))
```

Plotting the points on top of google map from `RgoogleMaps` is an option but the background is not white making the points difficult to see. Please advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(mapproj)

us <- map_data('world',
                   c('usa', 'canada', "hawaii", "mexico"))
ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=us, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), colour="grey20", fill="grey80")+
  geom_point(data = DATA, aes(x=Long, y = Lat), color = "red")+
  geom_text_repel(data = DATA, aes(x=Long, y = Lat, label = State), color = "red")+
  coord_map(projection = "mercator", xlim=c(-170, -50))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]